# Token for graph.microsoft.com from adal.js

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I have read a few stack questions.

I have a simple web application, authentication is working well. I just use ADAL and its working.

```
var endpoints = {
      "https://graph.microsoft.com": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
      'https://login.microsoftonline.com/':'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'
}

window.config = {
      tenant: 'xxx.com',
      clientId: guid,
      endpoints: endpoints,
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
};
```

I login with

```
authContext.login();
```

and I get a token with

```
authContext.acquireToken(config.clientId,
      function (error, token) {
            if (error) console.log(error);
            localStorage.setItem('token', token);
      }
);
```

That all works, I presume I need another token for `https://graph.microsoft.com` so I do

```
authContext.acquireToken('https://graph.microsoft.com',
      function (error, token) {
            console.log('callback token graph', token, error);            
            if (error) console.log(error);
            localStorage.setItem('gtoken', token);
      }
```

this never hits the call back. I have tried removing the first call to `acquireToken`

Or is my first token meant to be used with the Microsoft Graph calls (which is how I thought it should work at the start, I am kinda going around in circles:) )

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit the manifest as follows

```
"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
```

And revert loads of junk code that I added :)

The error was being swallowed due to other reasons. The ADAL requires that page to be rendered before it will work correctly. I had a few issues with the order things were happening.